# Configurable products with Customizable Options

Tags: magento2

I have a configurable product, whose attribute is color, and the user can change the color of the product. Also I have added customizable options, with the sizes that the user can change. But each article that is generated does not include these options, is this normal?

If I add a size attribute from the configuration tab, the system generates a product for each size and for each color, so many necessary products are created.

Comment: Yes Magento generats simple products with all combination of attributes of configurations.

Comment: There is way for create a product to inherit some of the father's attributes (not all)?